# jQuery to dynamically create complex HTML fragments

Tags: jquery, html, json

I wish to generate (or at least fill a template of some kind with JSON data and append to a list) a semi-complex HTML div element using jQuery. The data is in JSON format (if it matters) and for each parent entry I wish to add another div to a carousel-type element.

A long statement such as:

```
$('#list').append('<li><div id=" + entry.id +"><span id="highlight> + entry.name + <span/><div id="picture" ....
```

will work but is too hard to maintain (excuse errors there it's just to make a point). There must be a more efficient way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking into javascript templating languages - there are tons out there:

- [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template);
- [mustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/);
- [jade](http://jade-lang.com/);
- [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/);
- many more...

The idea is to keep data and its view separate:

```
var myUser = { name : 'John', lastname : 'Doe' };

$('#awesomeDiv').html(
    someTemplateFunction( { user : myUser } )
);
```

And `someTemplateFunction()` will hold in its body something like:

```
<p>Hello <strong><%=user.name %> <%=user.lastname %></strong></p>
```

By *holding* I mean that the template library is able to parse such template [coming from the DOM or from an external file] and to render it out to new DOM elements.

My pick is **underscore.js** because it's a very minimal yet useful library, feel free to look around.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for some templating. There are many:

- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [Hogan](http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/)
- [dust.js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/)
- [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)
- [underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template)
- [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will work for what you're doing but recently I had a similar issue and I didn't want to 'polute' my js with html to be inserted. My solution was to insert all the html in the page and let it hidden so that, when needed, I can just reveal it or, in some cases, I copy the desired div.

Comment: This is something I had considered, having a hidden div which I could clone. Just thought there may be cleaner options.

Comment: For most cases I believe there surely may be cleaner options. Unfortunately, for mine, I found none.